# Grails Spring Security ui plugin with ldap authorities?

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, spring-security-ldap

I have the Grails Spring Security ldap plugin working and connecting to my Active Directory. Now I am trying to add the Spring Security UI plugin to manage my AD users and roles. Is this possible?

It appears that the spring security ui plugin controllers only handle database user/role crud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, there's no support for managing LDAP in the UI plugin. I'm not sure how well-maintained it is, but the http://grails.org/plugin/ldap can manage LDAP.